# Can a KTX image file be a cubemap arrays?

Tags: c++, vulkan

**Is it valid for a KTX image to be a cubemaps arrays, or is that not a thing?**

I have some code that I'm currently using for uploading the data from a KTX file to the GPU. Currently, the code works for a regular 2d image, a cubemap, and a texture array. However, it would not support a KTX image that is a cubemap array, if that is a thing.

If it is possible, what is the code below missing to accomplish that?

```
uint32_t offset = 0;
for (uint32_t layer = 0; layer < layers; layer++) {
    for (uint32_t face = 0; face < faces; face++) {
        for (uint32_t level = 0; level < mipLevels; level++) {
            offset = tex->GetImageOffset(layer, face, level);
            vk::BufferImageCopy bufferCopyRegion = {};
            bufferCopyRegion.imageSubresource.aspectMask = vk::ImageAspectFlagBits::eColor;
            bufferCopyRegion.imageSubresource.mipLevel = level;
            bufferCopyRegion.imageSubresource.baseArrayLayer = (faces == 6 ? face : layer); // TexArray or Cubemap, not both.
            bufferCopyRegion.imageSubresource.layerCount = 1;
            bufferCopyRegion.imageExtent.width = width >> level;;
            bufferCopyRegion.imageExtent.height = height >> level;
            bufferCopyRegion.imageExtent.depth = 1;
            bufferCopyRegion.bufferOffset = offset;

            bufferCopyRegions.push_back(bufferCopyRegion);
        }
    }
}
```

Vulkan command to transfer the image.

```
// std::vector<vk::BufferImageCopy> regions;
cmdBuf->copyBufferToImage(srcBufferHandle, destImageHandle,
        vk::ImageLayout::eTransferDstOptimal, uint32_t(regions.size()), regions.data());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, KTX also supports cube map arrays (see the [KTX specification](http://github.khronos.org/KTX-Specification/)). Those are stored using layers.

The Vulkan spec states the following on how cube maps are stored in a cube map array:

> For cube arrays, each set of six sequential
> layers is a single cube, so the number of cube maps in a cube map array view is layerCount / 6, and
> image array layer (baseArrayLayer + i) is face index (i mod 6) of cube i / 6.

So you need to change the `baseArrayLayer` of your buffer copy region accordingly.

Sample code:

```
    // Setup buffer copy regions to get the data from the ktx file to your own image
    for (uint32_t layer = 0; layer < ktxTexture->numLayers; layer++) {
        for (uint32_t face = 0; face < 6; face++) {
            for (uint32_t level = 0; level < ktxTexture->numLevels; level++) {
                ktx_size_t offset;
                KTX_error_code ret = ktxTexture_GetImageOffset(ktxTexture, level, layer, face, &offset);
                VkBufferImageCopy bufferCopyRegion = {};
                bufferCopyRegion.imageSubresource.aspectMask = VK_IMAGE_ASPECT_COLOR_BIT;
                bufferCopyRegion.imageSubresource.mipLevel = level;
                bufferCopyRegion.imageSubresource.baseArrayLayer = layer * 6 + face;
                bufferCopyRegion.imageSubresource.layerCount = 1;
                bufferCopyRegion.imageExtent.width = ktxTexture->baseWidth >> level;
                bufferCopyRegion.imageExtent.height = ktxTexture->baseHeight >> level;
                bufferCopyRegion.imageExtent.depth = 1;
                bufferCopyRegion.bufferOffset = offset;
                bufferCopyRegions.push_back(bufferCopyRegion);
            }
        }
    }

    // Create the image view for a cube map array
    VkImageViewCreateInfo view = vks::initializers::imageViewCreateInfo();
    view.viewType = VK_IMAGE_VIEW_TYPE_CUBE_ARRAY;
    view.format = format;
    view.components = { VK_COMPONENT_SWIZZLE_R, VK_COMPONENT_SWIZZLE_G, VK_COMPONENT_SWIZZLE_B, VK_COMPONENT_SWIZZLE_A };
    view.subresourceRange = { VK_IMAGE_ASPECT_COLOR_BIT, 0, 1, 0, 1 };
    view.subresourceRange.layerCount = 6 * cubeMap.layerCount;
    view.subresourceRange.levelCount = cubeMap.mipLevels;
    view.image = cubeMap.image;
    vkCreateImageView(device, &view, nullptr, &cubeMap.view);
```

Comment: I looked at the KTX spec, chapter 4, but it didn't have enough info for me to figure out how to handle it. Also, I think section 4.1 might be incorrect. It defines layerCount for 2d images as  0, but the images I tested from your example (metalplate01_rgba.ktx & metalplate_nomips_rgba.ktx & crate01_color_height_rgba.ktx) all have layerCount of 1, which does make sense to me based on how the fetching code would be defined to iterate over layers, which should have 1 for 2d imager.

Comment: "But depending on how you store the array you may need to adjust you image sub resource to account for cube map arrays as layers are layed out consecutively, just as with a normal image array." -- This is, like, what I'm asking, though. I'm not sure how to do that. At the very least, the member `baseArrayLayer` seems like it wouldn't work.

Comment: From looking at the images in your Vulkan examples repo, I didn't see an image that's an array of textures. Does your repo have one?

Comment: I do have 2D texture arrays in my repo, but no cubemap arrays.

Comment: I updated my answer with a quote from the spec that hopefully clarifies how to address cube map array loading. The main difference is in the baseArrayLayer of your buffer copy.

Comment: Yeah, I meant cubemap arrays in your repo. Thanks man

Comment: I added working sample code. Never did this myself, so I had to test. I created a cube array with PVRTexTools, loaded it using above code and I could access the different cube maps stored in there.

Comment: Would you mind adding that cubearray image to your Vulkan repo? Also, thanks for posting the sample code. You're awesome.

Comment: Already working on it. I'll be adding a new sample that shows cube map array loading soon.